# How to make bash save a command to history at the moment a time-intensive command is issued, instead of only after the command ends or is killed?

Tags: bash, command-history

There are many questions with similar wording regarding how to save commands before exiting the session which answer something else (`PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`, `histopt` etc.).
This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140741/how-to-save-a-command-you-entered-without-executing-it) has a misleading wording, for instance, but talks about not fully typed commands instead.

I am asking about an earlier trigger for bash auto-saving a command.
For example, I need to see from another terminal a history already including any command with unfinished execution.

I suspect bash implementation won't be able to do that directly. However I think it worth asking.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/178801/bash-command-history-update-before-execution-of-command seems to be about the same wish, the solution suggested there is not straightforward though.

Comment: You could simply echo the intended command and append it to the history file. Then call it back from history to edit/execute as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following some ideias from the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/178801/bash-command-history-update-before-execution-of-command) mentioned by @Henrik in the comments section, putting this code at the end of `.bashrc` addressed my issue:

```
function saveafterenter {
   history -a
}
trap 'saveafterenter' DEBUG
```

*Note: some people use `history -c; history -r` in addition to `history -a`; this doesn't seem to be a good idea given the description in the  man page. It will affect the living history of other sessions. We usually don't want such a behavior. Each session is often more useful by branching the history in isolation until it is closed and its last command appended at the end of the history file. Intertwined sessions will alternate commands while appending to the file.*